# How do I pull my project from github?

Tags: git, github

I have a project on github that I have been working on before.  However, I wiped out my computer and I am wondering which git command should I invoke under my username to checkout my project again so that I can push my latest changes to github under my account.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Git clone is the command you're looking for:

```
git clone git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

Update:
And this is the official guide:
https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo

Take a look at:
https://help.github.com/

It has really useful content

Comment: Why do I always see things like `/path/repo.git` but when I clone a local repo I need to do `/path/repo/.git`  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 41):

First, you'll need to tell git about yourself. Get your username and token together from your [settings page](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

Then run:

```
git config --global github.user YOUR_USERNAME
git config --global github.token YOURTOKEN
```

You will need to [generate a new key](http://help.github.com/msysgit-key-setup/) if you don't have a back-up of your key.

Then you should be able to run:

```
git clone git@github.com:YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_PROJECT.git
```

Answer (score 19):

Run these commands:

```
cd /pathToYourLocalProjectFolder

git pull origin master
```

Comment: The OP says: _However, I wiped out my computer_, `/pathToYourLocalProjectFolder` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: You should replace the 'pathToYourLocalProjectFolder' with your actual path To  Local Project Folder.

Answer (score 8):

Since you have wiped out your computer and want to checkout your project again, you could start by doing the below initial settings:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email youremail@domain.com
```

Login to your github account, go to the repository you want to clone, and copy the URL under "Clone with HTTPS".

You can clone the remote repository by using HTTPS, **even if you had setup SSH the last time**:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repo-name.git
```

***NOTE:***

If you had setup SSH for your remote repository previously, you will have to add that key to the known hosts ssh file on your PC; if you don't and try to do `git clone git@github.com:username/repo-name.git`, you will see an error similar to the one below:

```
Cloning into 'repo-name'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.112)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXDoJWGl7E1IGOCspZomTxdCARLviMw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.255.112' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**Using HTTPS is a easier than SSH in this case.**

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in two ways,

**1. Cloning the remote repo to your localhost**

```
git clone https://github.com/user-name/repository.git
```

**2. Pulling the remote repo to your localhost**

First, you have to create a local git repo by,

```
git init or git init repo-name
```

then,

```
git pull https://github.com/user-name/repository.git
```

That's all, All commits and branch in the remote repo now available in your local repository.

Happy Coding, cheers -:)

Answer (score 3):

There are few steps to be followed (For Windows)

1. **Open Git Bash and generate ssh key**
   Paste the text below, substituting in your GitHub email address.

   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "*your_email@example.com*"

   This creates a new ssh key, using the provided email as a label.

   Generating public/private rsa key pair.

   When you're prompted to "Enter a file in which to save the key," press Enter. This 
   accepts the default file location.

   Enter a file in which to save the key (/c/Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa):[Press enter]

   At the prompt, type a secure passphrase. For more information, see "Working with SSH 
   key passphrases".

   Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Type a passphrase]
   Enter same passphrase again: [Type passphrase again]
2. **Add the key to SSH Agent**

   Type the following in Git Bash (99999 is just an example) to see agent is up and running.
   eval $(ssh-agent -s)
   Agent pid 99999

   then type this.

   ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa

   then Copy the SSH key to your clipboard using this command

   clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
3. **Add the SSH Key to the Git Account**

   In GitHib site, click on the image on top right corner, and select settings. In the subsequent page, click SSH and GPG keys option. This will open up the SSH key page. Click on the New SSH key. In the "Title" field, add a descriptive label for the new key. Paste your key into the "Key" field.
4. **Clone the Repository**

   Open VS Code (or any IDE/CLI which has command prompt etc.). Go to the directory in which you want to clone, using cd commands, and type the below line.
    git config --global github.user yourGitUserName
    git config --global user.email  your_email
    git clone git@github.com:yourGitUserName/YourRepoName.git

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Answer (score 0):

Note that for a specific branch **git clone is usually used once** (unless you want to copy your project in others folders/branch)

In your question the word "pull" is important since it is also a git command (git pull) which will pull changes made in a remote repo.

This precision just to avoid any confusions between clone and pull.