# Pulling down Github repo into Amazon ec2 Instance

Tags: github, amazon-ec2

Does anybody know how to pull down files from a Github repo onto an Amazon ec2 Instance using SSH. Something like `git clone 'git-repo-url'`. Also, could someone explain where on my ec2 instance I should pull this repo down onto if this is for a website? I'm successfully running apache however it's not showing my webpage...

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'Survey_app'.: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just

```
git clone https://github.com/path/to/your/directory
```

Depending on your operating system, it'll probably be somewhere like `/var/www/public_html` or  in the case of CentOS, `/var/www/html`

Comment: I tried this however it said permission denied...any idea why it would say that? I've added an SSH key from Github to Amazon so there shouldn't be a problem there I don't think...

Comment: Take a look at this: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git It helped me out when I started with Github

Comment: yup I just looked at it, but how is this going to help me with ec2? Not trying to be rude or anything I appreciate the link, just not sure how it solves the problem..

Comment: Are you having trouble getting into the instance?

Comment: nope. I'm SSHing fine into it. In fact, I'm even in the directory you set above /var/www/html as we type...

Comment: THis answer should help. Github needs to have your tokens (get those on your account page) to get your repo. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1408808/1415625

Comment: thanks again for the link, but I can't seem to find my account token and I read somewhere that git no longer supports tokens, is this true? I ran the first command to acknowledge my username, and it's still giving me the same error which I appended to my question..

Comment: What user are you logged in as? Type: `whoami` in the terminal

Comment: Sorry! I haven't used an ec2 image in a while. I use CentOS with EC2! Good luck!

Comment: Please don't apologize. You've been very helpful and helped me find the right answer, even if you didn't state it explicitly!